# opening a local .tex file in overleaf

Tags: overleaf, filesystem-access

I'd like to open a .tex file on my local system in overleaf.

The api allows for this over by passing the uri

```
https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=http://pathtoyourfile.tex
```

I would like to do

```
https://www.overleaf.com/docs?snip_uri=file:/path/to/file.tex
```

thank you for any help!

Comment: it's a general feature of URL handling that the part after `?` is handled at the server so you would need to run a web server at your side and use a form `?https://yourmachine/url-to-your-file`   there is no way the overleaf (or any) server is going to access files on your local disk via a file:// URL.

Comment: If that were possible overleaf could steal any file on your pc without you knowing it. Files have to be uploaded to overleaf and processed there end of story.

Answer (score 5):

(I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

The `file:` protocol is not supported. The URL needs to be fetchable by our servers. (From our servers' perspective, a URL with `file:` in it, and no internet-reachable hostname, would mean to look for the file *on our server itself*.)

If you don't have access to web hosting to upload files that you wish to use with the Overleaf API, one method is to add the file(s) to Dropbox or another file hosting service that provides public links. Then use the public link URL to the file as the `snip_uri`.

Depending on the sharing service, you may need to tweak the format of the sharing link in order for our server to fetch a raw copy of the file, not a wrapper page or landing page. More on this for various file-sharing services here: [How can I upload files from Google Drive?](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_can_I_upload_files_from_Google_Drive%3F)

On our [Overleaf API](https://www.overleaf.com/devs) page we also have some examples where the snippet content can be inlined in the request; however, if you need to pass in multiple files, the `snip_uri` method must be used.